# Triangle inequality for the $p$-adic metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, p-adic-number-theory

I try to understand the triangle inequality prove for the $p$-adic metric. The proof is given as:

$$\DeclareMathOperator{ord}{ord}|x-y|_p = p^{-\ord_p(x+y}\leq p^{-\min \{\ord_p(x),ord_p(y)\}}
 = \max \{p^{-\ord_p(x)},p^{-\ord_p(y)}\} = \max \{|x|_p,|y|_p\}$$

Now I don't understand why $p^{-\min \{\ord_p(x),\ord_p(y)\}} = \max \{p^{-\ord_p(x)},p^{-\ord_p(y)}\}$ how we went from min to max?

Comment: $p^{-n}$ varies inversely with $n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s a consequence of the minus sign in the exponent. Look at a concrete example:

$$p^{-\min\{2,3\}}=p^{-2}=\max\{p^{-2},p^{-3}\}\;,$$

for instance. Making a positive quantity $n$ **smaller** makes $p^{-n}$ **larger**.

Comment: Thanks prof. Scott! +1 Mind blowing how someone would downvote such a fine answer. What is going on here?

Answer (score 2):

The function $n \mapsto p^{-n}$ is strictly monotonically *decreasing*: 
$$n < m \implies p^{-n} > p^{-m}
$$